# GTest for a Method With Private Members That Depends on Clock Time

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a class with a public method that adds elements to a private vector and records the time when each element was added. Another public method in that class checks every element in the vector and removes ones that are older than 4 hours.

Those are the only public methods in the class (and there are no public members).

How can I use gtest to check that the remove function works?
I don't want the test to take 4 hours and I don't want to modify the source at all. Is this even possible?

**UPDATE**
GMock can override the method being used to get the current time. In many cases that will be a solution. However, GMock does not work for free functions (e.g. std::time). In that case, the GMock documentation only suggests [wrapping the function in a class](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions).
GMock will be useful, however, it's disappointing to find that it doesn't work for free functions and therefore the many cases where an STL free function or a function from a C-library needs to be mocked.  The GMock [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions) seems pretty clear about this but if someone happens to know a way around this (or another mocking framework without this limitation) let me know.

Comment: Why are you testing code that you can't modify?  What are you going to do if it fails a test?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your class testable, there is no other way. Even for the most basic meaningful test, you will need to expose several things.

First of all, you will need to control the timestamp attached to your elements. To do so, you will need to inject an object into a constructor of your class that will return the current time, something alongside:

```
class YourClass {
    // ...
    shared_ptr<Timer> timer;
public:
    YourClass(shared_ptr<Timer> t) : timer(t) {}
    void addElement(Element e) {
        e.timeAdded(timer->now());
        container.push_back(e);
    }
    // ...
};
```

In this way you can pass in a fake timer in tests, which will set whichever time you want. In this way you won't have to wait at all.

Then, you need to expose some interface to inspect the result. For example, make your function that removes old elements return how many it removed. This would be the easiest way.

If you are unwilling to make these or similar changes, then there is nothing you can do to test your code in any meaningful fashion.